# How to call "asp.net api upload file" from php

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, api

I create a serive api using asp.net and a methoad POST upload a any file, and I want using code php call that api, but i don't known how.

Code asp.net api upload file as follows:

```
public Task<IEnumerable<string>> Post()
    {
        if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            string fullPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/uploads");
            MyMultipartFormDataStreamProvider streamProvider = new MyMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(fullPath);
            var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);

                var fileInfo = streamProvider.FileData.Select(i =>
                {
                    var info = new FileInfo(i.LocalFileName);
                    return "File uploaded as " + info.FullName + " (" + info.Length + ")";
                });
                return fileInfo;

            });
            return task;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "Invalid Request!"));
        }
    }
```

And class:

```
public class MyMultipartFormDataStreamProvider : MultipartFormDataStreamProvider
{
    public MyMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(string path)
        : base(path)
    {

    }

    public override string GetLocalFileName(System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpContentHeaders headers)
    {
        string fileName;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(headers.ContentDisposition.FileName))
        {
            fileName = headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
        }
        else
        {
            fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".data";
        }
        return fileName.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

So, how to I can call this api using code php ?

I referenced code to: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/uploading-files-asynchronously-using-asp.net-web-api.htm

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you have a php website and looked on the web for an upload example and found a asp.net one.

If you got php running why not use php for the upload?